# How does UWP XAML recognize ImageSource conversion from string

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

The following is a perfectly valid XAML:

```xml
<Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png" />
```

The question is, how does UWP knows about converting this string to an `ImageSource`. I was expecting to see something like `IValueConverter` interface or `CreateFromString` attribute.

But these are the only attributes I can see:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But my question is specific to uwp not wpf

Comment: *How* is hidden in the details of the proprietary (non open-sourced) XAML compiler :)

Comment: @mm8 Is there a list of what property types are "kind of" special-cased in the XAML parser/compiler?

Comment: Not that I know of. But why do you need to know this? It's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

> How does UWP XAML recognize ImageSource conversion from string

[ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.sourceproperty?view=winrt-20348) is dependency property for Image control, it means that you could convert it to `BitmapImage` in the `PropertyChangedCallback` method.

When the source property changed, it will call the callback method, you could make BitmapImage with string url like the following.  For explain this you could make a [custom Dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties) property.

```
imageHolder.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///local/test.png"));
```

**Dependency**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UriProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Uri",
  typeof(String),
  typeof(CustomImage),
  new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUriChanged))
);
```

And please note Image is **sealed** type, you can't make a class derive from it

Comment: A dependency property alone won't tell the XAML parser anything about how to convert the string value to the property type. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not open source, above code is simulation, please check above `OnUriChanged` , you could call get method to get uri string value, then convert it as BitmapImage for image control.

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coded image path is to be converted to bitmap in compile time, so no String-to-ImageSource conversion is fulfilled in run-time. For the dynamicly specified path strings through {x:Bind}, UWP uses [XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbindinghelper.convertvalue) in code behind (auto-generated *.g.cs file in obj folder). Maybe XAML parser would be using something similar internally. If you'd like to take the same approach, try following code:

```
theImage.Source = XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(ImageSource), "/Assets/StoreLogo.png") as ImageSource;
```